# Extend appcompat textview style

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I need to set a custom style to all TextView/Button in my application (I need to change the font-family)

To achieve my intent I wrote the following code in my App Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>= 
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item> -->
</style>

<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
</style>
```

As you can see I'm using the AppCompat theme, but I cant figure out how to extend the correct textview. Infact I'm using `parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button"`but in this way I have lost the AppCompat button style.

PS: With that code all my textview and button change tha font-family, except for the toolbar and the NavigationView, is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a TextView not an AutocompleteTextView. Using Widget.AppCompat.textView I get an error "no resource found"

Comment: Try Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem or Widget.TextView

Comment: Try TextAppearance.AppCompat

Comment: <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item> .Not textViewStyle

Comment: I will go to bed.Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)
Copy over the variations of much needed font files in .ttf format (Roboto-Black.ttf,Roboto-Bold.ttf,RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf, Roboto-Regular.ttf, etc..) to 'assets' directory.(Create one if you do not have one yet in 'main' directory).

Step 2)
Create a file named 'fonts.xml' in 'xml' folder which should be inside 'res' directory. (res\xml\fonts.xml). Declare your preferred font names to match with its matching file names from 'assets' directory.

```
  <!-- Font with 10 styles defined -->
<family>
    <nameset>
        <name>rb_regular</name>
        <name>rb_bold</name>
        <name>rb_light</name>
        <name>rb_bolditalic</name>
        <name>rb_thin</name>
        <name>rb_medium</name>
        <name>rb_condensed_regular</name>
        <name>rb_condensed_light</name>
        <name>rb_condensed_bold</name>
        <name>rb_black</name>
    </nameset>
    <fileset>
        <file>Roboto-Regular.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Bold.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Light.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Thin.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Medium.ttf</file>
        <file>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</file>
        <file>RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf</file>
        <file>RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Black.ttf</file>
    </fileset>
</family>
```

Define them in your style files as below

```
//textviews
 <style name="TextViewRobotoRegular" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily"  tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">rb_regular</item>
</style>
<!-- Roboto-Bold-->
<style name="TextViewRobotoBold" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">rb_bold</item>
</style>
<!-- Roboto-Light-->
<style name="TextViewRobotoLight" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">rb_italic</item>
</style>
<!-- Roboto-BoldItalic-->
<style name="TextViewRobotoBoldItalic" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">rb_bolditalic</item>

</style>

//button
 <style name="RobotoRegular" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">rb_regular</item>
</style>
```

Finally use them in Layout files

```
                     <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewRobotoLight"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp" />
```